# Regular expression for multiple of 2 in java

Tags: java

I would like to know how to write regular expression for a multiple number of 2 .

For example :

2
4
6
8
10..

I want to ignore the odd number of  "%" and I want to split ",".

For example :

```
String.split("(?<!%{odd number}),");
```

Comment: "multiple of two" is an arithmetic problem, not a text processing problem.  You need an arithmetic solution (e.g some variant of `n %  2`), not a regex.  IMHO...

Comment: I search for escape character ( String.splits(",") but not before %).

Comment: String.split("(?<!%{2}),"); I tried.

Comment: Please provide sample input and output to clarify the question.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regular expression for this - it is overkill.

Instead you can simply divide by 2 and check if the remainder is 0 - if it is, then you know your number is a multiple of 2.

To get the remainder:

```
int x = 3;
int remainder = x % 2

if (remainder == 0) {
    //multiple of 2
} else {
    //not multiple of 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Martin Konecny** is so right about using regex for this matter which is a overkill, and other ways you can accomplish what you want are as follows :

If they prevent you to use `%` operand  you can use this way too

**Code:**

```
            try(Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)){
            System.out.print("Enter your number to see if it is odd or even: ");
            int result = input.nextInt();
            while( result >= 2){
                result -= 2; 
            }
            if ( result == 1) {
                System.out.println("odd");

            }else
                System.out.println("even ");
        }
```

**Explanation**: you keep subtracting 2 from the number when you get one it is odd otherwise it is even

Note: this is one interview question

**In `Java 8`**

Code:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
        list.stream()
            .filter( i -> i%2 == 0 )
            .forEach( i -> System.out.print(" " + i));
```

output:

```
 2 4
```

Comment: If they prevent you from using `%` you can use, somewhat more simply, `System.out.println(((result & 1) == 0) ? "even" : "odd");` ;-) If they prevent you from using `&` as well they are idiots, pure and simple.

Comment: @EJP so your are more concise

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input looks something like: `"%%%,%%,%%%%,%"` and you want to end up with `["%%","%%%%"]`, first split on the comma:

```
String[] split= "%%%,%%,%%%%,%".split(",");
```

Then filter out by the even number of '%'

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList();
for(String s:split){
    if(!s.matches("(%%)*%"))
        result.add(s);
}
System.out.println(result);
```